# Display symbol instead of '&#8734;' in perl

Tags: perl

I am parsing an HTML file and if `&#8734;` occurs which is displayed as `∞` in html page.

In perl when I try to take the data from the tags and when `&#8734;` occurs want to display  `∞` this symbol in perl through print STDERR.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by display? Display in a HTML page? Display to STDOUT? (If STDOUT please include your OS.) Or display using some other method like a GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/Entities.pm)?

Comment: Tried with HTML::Entities after your suggestion. used the method encode_entities($d); $d has infinite symbol. when printing this giving output as "&infin;" but i wan the infinite symbol

Comment: @Mohini — if you have an HTML entity and want a literal character then you need to **decode** it, not encode it.

Comment: used decode_entities($d); $d has `"& #8734;"`. but output is displayed as " Γê₧".

Comment: @Quentin : used decode_entities($d); $d has `"&#8734;"`. but output is displayed as " Γê₧". sorry to add another comment Already edited above  comment 5 times.

Comment: @Mohini — Your character encoding is being mangled somewhere. You haven't said where you are outputting the data to, so it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17231/discussion-between-mohini-and-quentin)